# Struggling to display django validation message

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I am trying to display an inbuilt Django validation error for my login form on my template I can't get any error message such as 'Username and Password do not match'. What am I doing wrong?
here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password'}))
    botcatcher = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
```

on my project url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='frontend/login.html', form_class=LoginForm), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='frontend/logout.html')),
    # path('backend/', include('backend.urls')),
    path('mrc/', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

on login.html

```
{% for my_field in form.visible_fields %}
                      <!-- THIS IS FOR ERROR IN THE FORM -->
                        {% if my_field.errors %}
                            {% for err in my_field.errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ err }}</div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                       <!-- THIS IS FOR THE FIELDS -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          {{ my_field.label_tag }}
                          {{ my_field }}

                        </div>
                        <!-- END THE FIELDS -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

`LoginView` does not have any specific field related error messages, only two non-field error messages for:

- invalid login and
- inactive user.

You can render these errors like this:

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks alot I am grateful for ur response it work!!

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for errors on the specific fields instead of checking the whole form for errors, try checking the whole form.

You can keep the regular field logic but try doing a separate check, so something like...

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
       {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
       {% endfor%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Basically, the form its self holds the errors, not the field. So your if statement will never be true even with errors in the form.